# Corrupt .tex file

Tags: errors

I am a recently new latex user and i'm having some problems with my .tex files.

Here's the actual code, totally corrupt and i don't know why

```
TeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages                (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count110
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen127
\Gin@req@width=\dimen128
)
("E:\Disco\ACADEMICO\LaTex\TPs Labo\TP 4 F2 B.aux")
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count111
\scratchdimen=\dimen129
\scratchbox=\box35
\nofMPsegments=\count112
\nofMParguments=\count113
\everyMPshowfont=\toks28
\MPscratchCnt=\count114
\MPscratchDim=\dimen130
\MPnumerator=\count115
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count116
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks29
) <wheatstone.jpg, id=1, 466.74374pt x 408.02437pt>
File: wheatstone.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)
 <use wheatstone.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: wheatstone.jpg used on input line 41.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 233.37129pt x 204.01169pt.

[1

{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}     <E:/Disco/ACADEMICO/LaTex/
TPs Labo/wheatstone.jpg>] [2] [3]
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 154--176


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 184--249

 []
```

Lots and lots underfull \hbox

```
 Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 184--249

 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 184--249

 []

[5] [6] [7]
Overfull \hbox (62.4382pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 254--271
 [] 
 []

[8] [9] ("E:\Disco\ACADEMICO\LaTex\TPs Labo\TP 4 F2 B.aux") ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3528 strings out of 493921
 44600 string characters out of 3144876
 123874 words of memory out of 3000000
 6791 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 10760 words of font info for 39 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 34i,16n,27p,361b,440s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files 
(x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb><C:/Program Files (x
86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86
)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/
MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/Mi
KTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi6.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTe
X 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2
.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX     2.9/
fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX     2.9/fon
ts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/
type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr8.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type
1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb><C:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/
public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy6.pfb>
Output written on "TP 4 F2 B.pdf" (9 pages, 254542 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 81 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 6 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

And here's a similar code.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Desktop} }
\usepackage{subfig}

\title {\Huge Leyes de Kirchoff}
\author{Z2172 - Jueves - Turno Noche - Grupo III}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Resumen}

    \begin{abstract}
                En el adjunto presentaremos la parte A de la experiencia realizada en
        la tercer concurrencia al laboratorio de Física II.
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}

%%% I. Introduccion Teorica
\section {Introducción Teórica}

Primera Ley de Kirchoff:    \hfill \\
Esta ley, llamada ley de los nudos, o nodos, establece que la suma de las 'n' intensidades incidentes es igual a la suma de las 'm' intensidades procedentes de los nodos.
\begin{center}
    $ \Sigma \ i_{n} \ = \Sigma \ i_{m} $
\end{center}

Segunda Ley de Kirchoff:    \hfill \\
Esta ley, llamada ley de las mallas, puede ser aplicada solo a circuitos de corrientes continua y establece que la suma algebraica de las diferencias de potencial encontradas en una malla, provocadas por cada elemento de la misma, recorrida en un sentido especifico es igual a 0.
\begin{center}
    $ \Sigma (V_{i} \ - \ V_{j}) \ = \ 0 $
\end{center}

%%% II. Objetivos del Experimento
\section {Objetivos del Experimento}

En el experimento haremos un estudio de un circuito de corriente continua y verificaremos que se cumplan las leyes de Kirchoff.

%%% II.I. Instrumental
\subsection {\large Instrumental}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{\tiny$\bullet$}

\begin{itemize}
        \item 4 pilas secas N$^{\circ}$6; 1,5V.
        \item 4 resistores fijos.
        \item 3 miliamperímetros.
        \item 3 interruptores.
        \item 1 voltímetro de elevada resistencia interna.
        \item Cables de conexión.
\end{itemize}

%%% III. Procedimientos
\section {Procedimientos}

Teniendo el circuito armado, procedimos a identificar cada elemento del mismo. Llevamos a su escala máxima cada instrumento de medición.
Luego comenzamos a medir la caída de tensión de cada pila individualmente, estando estas desconectadas, para poder determinar así su fuerza electromotriz.
Luego de esto, cerramos el circuito.
Se tomó nota de las distintas corrientes indicadas por los tres amperímetros, verificando que las mismas indiquen valores positivos, y luego comenzamos las mediciones de la malla 1.


El proceso de medición consistió en medir los diferentes potenciales entre el punto O y los distintos puntos solicitados (A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H y J). Estos valores fueron ingresados en la tabla para su posterior uso en los cálculos.

Finalmente, ya habiendo realizado todas las mediciones, se procedió a abrir el circuito y a realizar los diferentes cálculos requeridos.

%%% III.I Pasos a Seguir        
%\subsection {\large Pasos a seguir}    

%%% IV. Mediciones experimentales
\section {Mediciones Experimentales}

\tabulinesep = 2 mm

            \begin{table} [H]   
                \begin{center}
                    \begin{tabu} { |*{5}{c|} }
                        \hline
                        Pila & E$ _{1} $ & E$ _{2} $ & E$ _{3} $ & E$ _{4} $    \\ \hline
                        Tensión (Voltios) & 1,506 & 1,452 & 1,498 & 1,502   \\
                        \hline  
                    \end{tabu}
                    \caption{Valores de tensión de las pilas}
                \end{center}
            \end{table}

        \begin{table} [H]
            \centering
            \subfloat [Potenciales]{                    
                    \begin{tabu} { |*{2}{c|} }
                        \hline
                        Punto & V$_{j,o}$ (Voltios)
                        \\  \hline
                        A & 0
                        \\  \hline
                        B & -0,134
                        \\  \hline
                        C & 1,334
                        \\ \hline
                        D & 1,03
                        \\ \hline
                        E & -0,406
                        \\  \hline
                        F & -0,428
                        \\  \hline
                        G & -0,453
                        \\  \hline
                        H & 0,996
                        \\  \hline
                        J & 0
                        \\  \hline              
                    \end{tabu}
                %   \caption{Potenciales}
            }
            \   \   \
            \subfloat [Intensidades de las mallas]{
                    \begin{tabu} {|c|c|}
                        \cline {1-1}
                        $i$ (Amperios)
                        \\  \hline
                        0,028 & Malla I
                        \\  \hline
                        0,064 & Malla II
                        \\  \hline
                    \end{tabu}
                    %\caption{Intensidades de las mallas}
            }

        \end{table}

%%% V. Calculos
\section {Cálculos}

Los cálculos realizados para este trabajo serán especificados en la sección \underline{VII. Resultados} debido a que estos han sido sintetizados en una tabla.  \\  \hfill
Seran utilizadas las siguientes expresiones:
\begin{equation}
    R = \dfrac{V_{i} - V_{j}} {i}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    r = \dfrac{E - V} {i}
\end{equation}

%%% VI. Graficos
\section {Gráficos}

Gráficos adjuntos.

%%% VI. Resultados
\section {Resultados}

Los cálculos de la experiencia fueron realizados de manera tal que pudieran ser confeccionados sobre una tabla por lo que diferenciaremos los cálculos a realizar por cada columna de la misma.
\\  \hfill  \\  
Columna 1: En esta columna calcularemos las diferencias de potencial que existen entre cada punto del Cuadro (a) en la sección \underline{IV. Mediciones experimentales}.
\\  \hfill  
Columna 2: En esta columna especificaremos que expresión sera utilizada para obtener los datos de la columna 3.
\\  \hfill  
Columna 3: En esta columna calcularemos, a partir de las expresiones (1) y (2) especificadas en la columna 2, la resistencias correspondientes a cada elemento.
\\

    \begin{table} [H]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabu} { |*{3}{c|} }
                \hline
                $V_{i} - V_{j} $ (Voltios) & Expresión a utilizar & $R_{i,j}$ (Ohm)
                \\  \hline
                0,134 & 1 & 4,78
                \\  \hline
                -1,468 & 2 & 1,35
                \\  \hline
                0,304 & 1 & 10,86
                \\  \hline
                1,436 & 2 & 0,57
                \\  \hline
                0,022 & 1 & 0,78
                \\  \hline
                0,025 & 1 & 0,39
                \\  \hline
                -1,449 & 2 & 076
                \\  \hline
                0,996 & 1 & 15,56
                \\  \hline
            \end{tabu}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}

%%% VI.I Conclusiones
\subsection {Conclusiones}

Determinamos de manera experimental el cumplimiento de las leyes de Kirchoff, la primera dice: En cualquier nodo, la suma de las corrientes que entran en ese nodo es igual a la suma de las corrientes que salen. En nuestro caso, al medir la corriente con los amperímetros en el circuito, la corriente $i_{2}$ nos dio como era de esperar, la suma de $i_{1}$ + $i_{3}$ con lo que verificamos el cumplimiento de la ley.

La segunda ley: La suma algebraica de las diferencias de potencial eléctrico en un lazo es igual a cero. Al sumar las caídas de potencial en la malla uno de nuestro circuito nos dio aproximadamente cero, con lo que verificamos que también se cumple la segunda ley de Kirchoff. Los pequeños errores de medición se deben al tomar la lectura.

\end{document}
```

What do you think?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "totally corrupt" - the first extract you have provided looks like a pretty standard `.log` file, which is not a `.tex` file - but I don't understand what you were expecting to see. The under/overfull `\hbox`es are relatively minor TeX warnings telling you that it has had difficulty placing the output on the page and has had to put too few characters etc. on a line, or too many. Overfull `\hbox`es will result in text running into the margin and underfull ones will generally mean the output looks below par. This should be corrected but is not corruption.

Comment: You are using `\\ ` to break lines. That is always going to produce warnings like this. You shouldn't break lines this way except in special contexts e.g. `tabular`, `array` etc. Using `H` for the floats is not going to help either.  Let the floats float and LaTeX will be able to layout the page better.

Comment: And I recommend not using `tabu` unless you enjoy unpleasant surprises. At some point, your code will break as the author has promised backwards-incompatible changes. Meanwhile, bugs will not be fixed, however serious.

Comment: Most of that code has nothing to do with the 3 warnings it produces and could be eliminated from your example.

Comment: By the way (I don't think any of the answers so far have mentioned it), when using single or double quotes ('text' or "text") the opening quotes must use `\`` and `\`\`` and the closing quotes should ideally use `''` (that's two separate `'`s). There are ways around this, but you will notice that your output looks wrong, with two closing quotes surrounding your 'n', for instance. Instead you should have `\`n'`, or `\`\`n''`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give you a starting point:

You have a lot of errors or unlucky coding in your given MWE.  I corrected them (parts) to show you where you could do it better with a better layout ;-)

I killed your `\\ \hfill \\` lines. Please **never** do that. LaTeX is very good to use proper spacing between paragraphy for you, so just use an empty line (see the commented ones in my code and compare the result of mine with yours ...).

Numbers should not stay alone at the beginning of a line. So please always write `dumy text~0` to force LaTeX to do not break the line between the word (`text`) and the number (`0`).  And do not start an list entry with a number `4`.  In this case it is better to write `four` or `Four`.

The biggest error was to make an reference to an chapter/section by hand. Please **never** do that, you will only produce errors.  LaTeX can do that for you with for example:

```
\section {Mediciones Experimentales}\label{sec:4}
```

The added `\label{sec:4}` makes a reference marking point you can refer to with command `\ref{sec:4}`. Best practice is to use `sec` to mark it is a section, then `:` to mark the second part of the label and `4` to visualise your section 4.  Better is to use a **name** you can better remember, for example for section 7: `\label{sec:result}`. **Be careful:** Do not use non ASCII letters there, like `ó` etc inside the `\label` and `\ref` command!!

I changed your `tabu` tables to `tabular`.  `tabu` results often in errors, do not use it ...

Equations place in environments for equations, like `equation` or `align` (if you have to write more than one equation). Details please see in my MWE.

If you have a mathematics term in your text just use `$i_{1}+i_{3}$` (include +, = etc. between the two `$`s!  You need not to write spaces in your equation, LaTeX knows better where it has to use a space or that variables have to be set in italic etc.  In your given equation in section 5 you can use `\frac` instead of `\dfrac` (to use bigger letters as in display modus), because you are in the display modus.  Depending on the mathematics in your document consider to use package `amsmath` which gives a better mathematical typography. Use `\sum` to write the summation sign.  Use `\sum_{i=1}^{100}`  to add the limits `i=1` and `100` to the summation sign (see the example in my code).

See section one for better coding and better result: Choose if you want to the format for the first or the second law (see code).

The sign between the several authors should be better `--` or `---` depending on the rules of your language (I sadly not know). I used `--` to show the difference.

I suggest to read an introduction to LaTeX, sorry I do not know one in your language.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
% draft,% <=============================================================
  12pt, 
  a4paper,
  spanish,% <===========================================================
]{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Desktop} }
\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{csquotes}% <===================== language depending quoting
\usepackage{showframe}% <===============================================
\usepackage{hyperref}% <================================================

\title {\Huge Leyes de Kirchoff}
\author{Z2172 -- Jueves -- Turno Noche -- Grupo III}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Resumen}

\begin{abstract}
  En el adjunto presentaremos la parte A de la experiencia realizada en
  la tercer concurrencia al laboratorio de Física II.
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}} 
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\Roman{subsection}}

%%% I. Introduccion Teorica
\section {Introducción Teórica}

Primera Ley de Kirchoff:%    \hfill \\

Esta ley, llamada ley de los nudos, o nodos, establece que la suma de 
las \enquote{n} intensidades incidentes es igual a la suma de las 
\enquote{m} intensidades procedentes de los nodos. % <=== needs csquotes!
\begin{equation*}
  \sum i_{n}=\sum i_{m} 
\end{equation*}

\emph{Segunda Ley de Kirchoff:} 
Esta ley, llamada ley de las mallas, puede ser aplicada solo a circuitos 
de corrientes continua y establece que la suma algebraica de las 
diferencias de potencial encontradas en una malla, provocadas por cada 
elemento de la misma, recorrida en un sentido especifico es igual a~0.
\begin{align}
  \sum(V_{i}-V_{j})&=0 \\% <======== here you need \\ to get to the next line!
                  E&=m \cdot c^2 \\% here you need \\ to get to the next line!
  \sum_{i=1}^{100}i&=?\label{eq:gauss}% <===============================
\end{align} % use & to mark what has to be right above (= above next line =)
BTW: The German Gauss was fast to solve equation~\eqref{eq:gauss} in school.

%%% II. Objetivos del Experimento
\section{Objetivos del Experimento}

En el experimento haremos un estudio de un circuito de corriente 
continua y verificaremos que se cumplan las leyes de Kirchoff.

%%% II.I. Instrumental
\subsection{Instrumental}

\renewcommand\labelitemi{\tiny$\bullet$}

\begin{itemize}
  \item four pilas secas N$^{\circ}$6; 1,5V. % <===========================
  \item 4 resistores fijos.
  \item 3 miliamperímetros.
  \item 3 interruptores.
  \item 1 voltímetro de elevada resistencia interna.
  \item Cables de conexión.
\end{itemize}

%%% III. Procedimientos
\section{Procedimientos}

Teniendo el circuito armado, procedimos a identificar cada elemento del 
mismo. Llevamos a su escala máxima cada instrumento de medición. Luego 
comenzamos a medir la caída de tensión de cada pila individualmente, 
estando estas desconectadas, para poder determinar así su fuerza 
electromotriz. Luego de esto, cerramos el circuito. Se tomó nota de las 
distintas corrientes indicadas por los tres amperímetros, verificando 
que las mismas indiquen valores positivos, y luego comenzamos las 
mediciones de la malla~1.

El proceso de medición consistió en medir los diferentes potenciales 
entre el punto~O y los distintos puntos solicitados (A, B, C, D, E, F, 
G, H y~J). Estos valores fueron ingresados en la tabla para su 
posterior uso en los cálculos.

Finalmente, ya habiendo realizado todas las mediciones, se procedió a 
abrir el circuito y a realizar los diferentes cálculos requeridos.

%%% III.I Pasos a Seguir        
%\subsection {\large Pasos a seguir}    

%%% IV. Mediciones experimentales
\section {Mediciones Experimentales}\label{sec:4}

%\tabulinesep = 2 mm

\begin{table} [H]   
  \caption{Valores de tensión de las pilas}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular} { |*{5}{c|} }
    \hline
    Pila              & E$_{1}$ & E$_{2}$ & E$ _{3}$ & E$_{4}$ \\ \hline
    Tensión (Voltios) & 1,506   & 1,452   & 1,498    & 1,502   \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

        \begin{table} [H]
            \centering
            \subfloat [Potenciales]{                    
                    \begin{tabular} { |*{2}{c|} }
                        \hline
                        Punto & V$_{j,o}$ (Voltios)
                        \\  \hline
                        A & 0
                        \\  \hline
                        B & -0,134
                        \\  \hline
                        C & 1,334
                        \\ \hline
                        D & 1,03
                        \\ \hline
                        E & -0,406
                        \\  \hline
                        F & -0,428
                        \\  \hline
                        G & -0,453
                        \\  \hline
                        H & 0,996
                        \\  \hline
                        J & 0
                        \\  \hline              
                    \end{tabular}
                %   \caption{Potenciales}
            }
            \   \   \
            \subfloat [Intensidades de las mallas]{
                    \begin{tabular} {|c|c|}
                        \cline {1-1}
                        $i$ (Amperios)
                        \\  \hline
                        0,028 & Malla I
                        \\  \hline
                        0,064 & Malla II
                        \\  \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                    %\caption{Intensidades de las mallas}
            }

        \end{table}

%%% V. Calculos
\section{Cálculos}

Los cálculos realizados para este trabajo serán especificados en la 
sección~\ref{sec:results} debido a que estos han sido sintetizados en una tabla.%  \\  \hfill

Seran utilizadas las siguientes expresiones:
\begin{equation}
    R=\frac{V_{i}-V_{j}}{i}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    r = \dfrac{E - V} {i}
\end{equation}
and compare please with this layout:
\begin{align}
    R&=\frac{V_{i}-V_{j}}{i} \\% here you need \\ to get to the next line!
    r&=\frac{E-V}{i}
\end{align}

%%% VI. Graficos
\section {Gráficos}

Gráficos adjuntos.

%%% VI. Resultados
\section{Resultados}\label{sec:results}

Los cálculos de la experiencia fueron realizados de manera tal que pudieran ser confeccionados sobre una tabla por lo que diferenciaremos los cálculos a realizar por cada columna de la misma.

%\\  \hfill  \\  
Columna 1: En esta columna calcularemos las diferencias de potencial que existen entre cada punto del Cuadro (a) en la sección~\ref{sec:4}, page~\pageref{sec:4}.

%\\  \hfill  
Columna 2: En esta columna especificaremos que expresión sera utilizada para obtener los datos de la columna 3.

%\\  \hfill  
Columna 3: En esta columna calcularemos, a partir de las expresiones (1) y (2) especificadas en la columna 2, la resistencias correspondientes a cada elemento.
%\\

    \begin{table} [H]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tabular} { |*{3}{c|} }
                \hline
                $V_{i} - V_{j} $ (Voltios) & Expresión a utilizar & $R_{i,j}$ (Ohm)
                \\  \hline
                0,134 & 1 & 4,78
                \\  \hline
                -1,468 & 2 & 1,35
                \\  \hline
                0,304 & 1 & 10,86
                \\  \hline
                1,436 & 2 & 0,57
                \\  \hline
                0,022 & 1 & 0,78
                \\  \hline
                0,025 & 1 & 0,39
                \\  \hline
                -1,449 & 2 & 076
                \\  \hline
                0,996 & 1 & 15,56
                \\  \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{table}

%%% VI.I Conclusiones
\subsection {Conclusiones}

Determinamos de manera experimental el cumplimiento de las leyes de Kirchoff, la primera dice: En cualquier nodo, la suma de las corrientes que entran en ese nodo es igual a la suma de las corrientes que salen. En nuestro caso, al medir la corriente con los amperímetros en el circuito, la corriente $i_{2}$ nos dio como era de esperar, la suma de $i_{1}+i_{3}$ con lo que verificamos el cumplimiento de la ley.

La segunda ley: La suma algebraica de las diferencias de potencial eléctrico en un lazo es igual a cero. Al sumar las caídas de potencial en la malla uno de nuestro circuito nos dio aproximadamente cero, con lo que verificamos que también se cumple la segunda ley de Kirchoff. Los pequeños errores de medición se deben al tomar la lectura.

\end{document}
```

With adding package `hyperref` the `\ref` commands get clickable in your pdf file ...

Result page 1 (see sum sign and authors):

[image: Result page 1]

Result page 3 (see red marking for hyperlinks to other section and equations):

[image: Result page 3]

Package `showframe` is used to visualise the typing area, comment it if not longer needed.

Tables should have a heading above the table not below (see table 1).  Better is to get rid of the many lines you have. I suggest to read documentation of package `bookmarks` (`texdoc bookmarks` on your console/terminal).

Btw:  **This MWE compiles with 0 errors and 0 warnings!**

Comment: This is a very good and helpful guide to improving the source. I would recommend pointing out to the OP that explicit horizontal spaces before operators such as `-` and `=` need to be removed. `\dfrac` is also not necessary within a displaymath environment. not that it does any harm, but as a learning point, at least, it's worth noting :)

Comment: Also I *suspect* that where the OP has `\Sigma` they probably wanted `\sum`

Comment: I did not get any errors at all. Just 3 warnings.

Answer (score 4):

The code compiles fine with 3 warnings concerning overfull and underfull boxes. This provides line numbers in the output which identifies the following lines as the problem:

```
Los cálculos de la experiencia fueron realizados de manera tal que pudieran ser confeccionados sobre una tabla por lo que diferenciaremos los cálculos a realizar por cada columna de la misma.
\\  \hfill  \\  
Columna 1: En esta columna calcularemos las diferencias de potencial que existen entre cada punto del Cuadro (a) en la sección \underline{IV. Mediciones experimentales}.
\\  \hfill  
Columna 2: En esta columna especificaremos que expresión sera utilizada para obtener los datos de la columna 3.
\\  \hfill  
Columna 3: En esta columna calcularemos, a partir de las expresiones (1) y (2) especificadas en la columna 2, la resistencias correspondientes a cada elemento.
\\
```

So, this is a suitable MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
Los cálculos de la experiencia fueron realizados de manera tal que pudieran ser confeccionados sobre una tabla por lo que diferenciaremos los cálculos a realizar por cada columna de la misma.
\\  \hfill  \\
Columna 1: En esta columna calcularemos las diferencias de potencial que existen entre cada punto del Cuadro (a) en la sección \underline{IV. Mediciones experimentales}.
\\  \hfill
Columna 2: En esta columna especificaremos que expresión sera utilizada para obtener los datos de la columna 3.
\\  \hfill
Columna 3: En esta columna calcularemos, a partir de las expresiones (1) y (2) especificadas en la columna 2, la resistencias correspondientes a cada elemento.
\\
\end{document}
```

which produces these warnings concerning boxes:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 21--29
Overfull \hbox (35.52892pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 21--29
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 21--29
```

The first problem here is the use of `\\` to break lines. This should never be done outside special contexts such as `tabular` and `array` environments.

The spacing here seems a little weird and I don't know why you would want bigger space - intermediate space - intermediate space - small space. But, if you do, you do:

```
Los cálculos de la experiencia fueron realizados de manera tal que pudieran ser confeccionados sobre una tabla por lo que diferenciaremos los cálculos a realizar por cada columna de la misma.
\bigskip

Columna 1: En esta columna calcularemos las diferencias de potencial que existen entre cada punto del Cuadro (a) en la sección \underline{IV. Mediciones experimentales}.
\medskip

Columna 2: En esta columna especificaremos que expresión sera utilizada para obtener los datos de la columna 3.
\medskip

Columna 3: En esta columna calcularemos, a partir de las expresiones (1) y (2) especificadas en la columna 2, la resistencias correspondientes a cada elemento.
\smallskip
```

Or you can use something like `\vskip .5ex plus .25ex` or whatever. Make sure you include some stretch if you specify it explicitly. If you absolutely must have a specific space no matter what `\vspace{1ex}` or whatever is an option, but not a good one if you can help it.

The above gets rid of 2 warnings, leaving just 1 of the 3:

```
Overfull \hbox (35.52892pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 24--26
```

This is our overfull box - too much stuff, rather than too little. The output makes this clear:

[image: too much stuff]

The problem here is that `\underline{}` boxes its content and cannot be broken across lines. The first thing to ask yourself is whether you *really* need underlining at all. Underlining is horrible in body text. It was used on typewriters because it was one of very few alternative styles of text available. (No italics; bold if you over-typed, but not very satisfactory.) You are not similarly limited.

If this is just a cross-reference, I definitely would not underline it. I wouldn't format it specially at all.

Also, if this is a cross-reference, you should be using `\label{}` and `\ref{}` and not manually specifying the number of the section.

However, assuming it is not a cross-reference and your institutional or submission guidelines force you to create a typographical monstrosity, so that you literally have no choice but to underline (or fail your degree or whatever, which might be worth it but probably not), then you need to either look for these cases and rephrase to avoid bad breaks. Or you need to use breakable underlining using something like `soul`.

Adding

```
\usepackage{soulutf8}
```

and changing `\underline` to \ul`, the remaining warning is banished and the output looks better, too:

[image: breakable underlining]

However, you really do not want to do things this way. You should use semantic markup. This is LaTeX, if you are entering numbers manually (except references to e.g. books or other people's documents or whatever), then you are making your document harder to maintain and more prone to error and inconsistency.

Also, saying `a4paper` is no good. At best you will get `letterpaper` layout on A4. Adding `geometry` will fix this, for example.

More could be done, but something like this would be better:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newlist{columna}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[columna]{label={Columna \arabic*:}, wide, ref={columna \arabic*}}
\newlist{parenum}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[parenum]{label={(\arabic*)}}
\renewcommand\thesection{\Roman{section}}
\begin{document}
\section{First}

\section{Second}

\section{Third}

\section {Mediciones Experimentales}\label{sec:medexp}

\section{Fifth}

Los cálculos de la experiencia fueron realizados de manera tal que pudieran ser confeccionados sobre una tabla por lo que diferenciaremos los cálculos a realizar por cada columna de la misma.
\begin{columna}
  \item\label{col:onething} En esta columna calcularemos las diferencias de potencial que existen entre cada punto del Cuadro (a) en la \cref{sec:medexp} Mediciones experimentales.
  \item\label{col:something} En esta columna especificaremos que expresión sera utilizada para obtener los datos de la \ref{col:else}.
  \item\label{col:else} En esta columna calcularemos, a partir de las expresiones \begin{parenum}\item y \item especificadas\end{parenum} en la \ref{col:something}, la resistencias correspondientes a cada elemento.
\end{columna}

\end{document}
```

[image: automated output]

The basic idea is that you let the computer do all the stuff computers are great at and humans are crap at. This includes all those fiddly details like remembering to change all instances of `IV.` if you insert a new section between sections 2 and 3 so it is now `V.`, and remembering which order items are given in, and formatting lists and references consistently throughout the document and so on.

LaTeX is great at this. We, on the other hand, are awful at it.